How do I create a unique index across multiple JSONB fields with Knex?
I have the following Knex migration (using Postgresql):
import { Knex } from 'knex';

export async function up(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
  await knex.schema.createTable('cars', (table: any) => {
    table.string('id', 25).primary();
    table.jsonb('car').notNullable().unique(["car->>'year'","car->>'model'","car->>'color'"], {indexName: 'unique_cars'});
  });
}

export async function down(knex: Knex): Promise<void> {
  await knex.schema.dropTableIfExists('cars');
}


When I run the migration I get a unique index BUT it is based off of car and not the fields I specified:
SELECT * FROM pg_indexes WHERE tablename = 'cars';
schemaname | tablename  |          indexname          | tablespace |                                           indexdef                                           
------------+------------+-----------------------------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public     | cars | cars_pkey             |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX cars ON public.cars USING btree (id)        
 public     | cars | cars_car_unique |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX cars_car_unique ON public.cars USING btree (car)
(2 rows) 




